# Dynamic Storage file retrieve

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

I've managed to retrieve a hardcoded image using this (got the base from [this](https://github.com/bradtraversy/proplistings)):

listings.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FirebaseService} from '../../services/firebase.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listings',
  templateUrl: './listings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listings.component.css']
})
export class ListingsComponent implements OnInit {
  listings:any;
  image:string;

  constructor(private firebaseService:FirebaseService) {
    let image = firebase.storage().ref().child('myFolder/myImage.jpg').getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
        // Set image url
        this.image = url;
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firebaseService.getListings().subscribe(listings => {
      console.log(listings);
      this.listings = listings;
    });
  }

}
```

But I cannot figure out how to dynamically retrieve an image using something like

```
<div *ngFor="let listing of listings">
  <img src="{{'myFolder/' + listing.path + '.jpg'}}" />
</div>
```

Comment: Just a shot here, as I'm in a hurry, but interpolating the whole string doesn't seem right. Try something like `[src]="'myFolder/' + listing.path + '.jpg'"`. Note that you can bind to the `src` property with the square brackets, which eliminates the need for interpolation.

Comment: @J.AdamConnor oh well yes, that was a habit from AngularJS :D the problem is another btw, it's that Firebase needs a function to get an image saved into its Storage, and I don't know how to dynamically request them because of the way `getDownloadUrl()` works (it needs a path). Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering if you can join the path to the listings Observable.

So in your service:

```js
getListings(): Obserable<any> {
    let results = this.af.database.list(`path/to/data`)
    // Each time getListings() emits, switch to unsubscribe/ignore
    // any pending member queries:
    .switchMap(listings => {
        // Map the listings to the array of observables that are to be
        // joined. When the observables emit a value, update the listing.
        let joinedObservables: any[] = []
        listings.forEach(listing => {
            // Does the listing contain the string you want to plug into the path? 
            // If so...
            joinedObservables.push(firebase.storage().ref().child(`myFolder/${listing.path}`).getDownloadURL()
            // I'm a little unsure of whether this can be done here.
            .then(url => {
                listing.imagePath = url
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
            )
        })            
        // Join the member observables and use the result selector to
        // return the listings - which will have been updated.
        return Observable.combineLatest(joinedObservables, () => listings)
    })
    return results
}
```

Component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.listings = this.firebaseService.getListings()
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let listing of listings | async">
    <img [src]="listing.imagePath">
</div>
```

I'm guessing this will need some adjusting. Or it may not work at all. If nothing else consider that this might be a task better suited for your service. Remember also that you are going to have to import the operators used; e.g., `switchMap` (which is imported as `flatMap`) and  `combineLatest`.

Comment: Uhm, I don't know why but with the Service I'm getting this error: `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.`

I've imported `import {Observable} from 'rxjs';` and neither `switchMap` nor `combineLatest` are giving me errors, am I missing something?

Comment: return statements were in the wrong place. edited the answer. try again.

Comment: OMG IT WORKS THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was getting broken URLs so I checked what was going wrong and I had just to change `listingimages/${listing.path}.jpg` into `${listing.path}` and was alright! Thank you again!

Comment: Glad I could help. Yeah, I wasn't sure what image.path looked like.